# Difference between memory size and memory locations?

Tags: memory, memory-management, cpu-architecture, memory-address

I am trying to understand the **Memory size** and locations of a **8 bits** architecture main memory , just tell me if a cell of memory contains 8 bits= 1 byte storage/size, then how much data of instructions **CPU** fetch from that particular cell of that memory , is it 8 bits(1 byte) or 2^8= 256 bits? if your answer is 256 bits then why it is written in the book that each cell contains 8 bits not 256 bits , in my general knowledge a CPU should fetch 8 bits of instructions if that cell contains 8 bits.

Comment: Why do you think it might be 2^8 = 256 bits (32 bytes)?  It's not, but without understanding why you thought it might be, we can't correct whatever misunderstanding you might be wondering about.

Comment: @peter i realised that it was a misunderstanding that's why i asked for help, sorry if i did anything wrong

Comment: Next time you have a question about a misunderstanding, present your reasoning for how you got to the wrong answer.  In this case, it's not at all obvious what misunderstanding might have led to that guess; I can't think of one, and the two answers had to guess.  (I also wondered if memory addresses themselves are 8 bits wide on this machine, i.e. there are only 256 bytes of memory total.  In real life, most 8-bit architectures had 16-bit pointers so they could have a useful amount of 8-bit bytes, but a hypothetical 8-bit machine without that is possible.)

Comment: You accepted an answer that implies this 8-bit architecture had a cache, with a line size of 32 bytes.  Possible I guess, but weird (usually 8-bit CPUs are too simplistic to have any cache), and pulling in the surrounding cache line (32 total cells, 256-bits) when you access one cell is not the same as fetching 32 bytes from that one cell so it doesn't match how you described it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs more clarification, but for the simple case, a very basic CPU working on a single instruction at a time will read 8 bits from this memory cell assuming its instruction size is 8 bits.

However in modern CPU architecture, It simply contains multi-level instruction caches and uses them to store multiple instructions from a single read to the main memory. (i.e. CPU reads a block (multiple memory cells) from main memory and get multiple instructions at once storing them to the caches).
Although, you didn't mention a cache in your question, The book could meant that the CPU will read multiple blocks/locations representing multiple instructions and store them in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

We need the concepts of count of digits, N, verses number of different values, V, given number base, B, for the digits.

V = B<sup>N</sup>

The formula works for base 10: for example, working with decimal digits, base is B=10, a count of N=3 digits can represent V=1000 different values with those three digits, with the range: 000-999.

When the base is 2, a digit is a bit.  A count of N=8 bits can represent/store/communicate V=256 different values, with the range: 00000000-11111111).

So, we have to keep our count of digits separate from number of different values those digits can take on.

In reverse the formula is:

N = log<sub>B</sub>( V )

So, log<sub>2</sub>( 256 ) = 8, which says that if we want to be able to have 256 different values, we need 8 bits.

8 ***bits*** or binary digits can represent 256 different ***values*** or numbers.