# Why is the maximum addressable memory 2^ bits

Tags: memory, mips, memory-address

Not really sure how to phrase my question, but in my Computer Systems course, we learned that max addressable memory is 2 ^ bits.

So for example, the max size of addressable memory in a 32 bit processor is 2^32 = 4GB.

Why is this the case?

Comment: It's just the number of possible distinct values an n-bit value can have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between memory size and memory locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325684/difference-between-memory-size-and-memory-locations)

Answer (score 1):

In a 32 bit system, the registers inside the CPU are 32-bit and thus cannot address more than 32 bit, while in a 64-bit system the registeres are 64-bit and can address more memory.